error occured when run setpci reading in multithreading
when i run below code without remove code, it's ok. but after removed first BDF in a thread there will be a error when reading DSP with setpci in other thread like:
setpci: Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/devices/bdf/resource: No such file or directory
I don't konw why this happend since I only removed BDF and all I do with setpci is about DSP.
def read(dsp,bdf):
    res=os.popen('sudo setpci -s '+dsp+' 0x3e.w').read().strip()
    logging.info(threading.current_thread().name+' :'+res)
    os.system('echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/'+bdf+'/remove')
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/'+dsp+'/rescan')

for i,bdf in enumerate(bdfs):
        dsp=get_dsp(bdf)
        threading.Thread(target=read,args=(dsp,bdf),name=bdf).start()

some log:
0000:0e:00.0 :0003
setpci: Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0e:00.0/resource: No such file or directory
0000:0f:00.0 :


it seems caused by setpci, but I don't konw why setpci reading DSP need open USP resource
